# Dependent unemployed adult sons not getting visa to UK. Would it be reasonable to plan a family holiday for all to meet up in Europe or Canada?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, canada

Dependent unemployed adult sons not getting visa to UK. Would it be reasonable to plan a family holiday for all to meet up in Europe or Canada?
The reason they are not getting a visa to UK is that my wife and I are resident here.

Comment: How would they demonstrate intention to return to their country of residence?

Comment: Perhaps go to India to visit them or go to a country where Indians don't need visas or get visas on arrival, maybe a Caribbean holiday? https://www.makemytrip.com/blog/visa-on-arrival-for-indians

Comment: Note: for more context on this question, refer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121885/repeated-visa-refusals-of-adult-sons-living-in-india-parents-resident-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 4):

Your sons aren't getting visitor visas for Britain because they are considered to be at a high risk of overstaying **in their own right**. Your presence in the UK only exacerbates that.

Is it reasonable to plan a holiday elsewhere? Yes, but many of the same factors would apply wherever they might wish to go. There is no way for us to assess the likelihood of your sons being granted European or Canadian visas. They will have to apply and take their chances.

Be aware that repeated refusals will count against them if asked, and the reasons for those refusals will have to be addressed. As Traveller says in the comments, how will they demonstrate their intention to return to India after the visit?